# Continuity of the ratio of the integral of a product normalized by the individual integrals

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $u:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,u_\text{max}]$ and $v:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,v_\text{max}]$ be continuous functions and define $w(u,v)$ as

$$w(u,v) = \frac{\int_0^1 u(x) v(x) dx}{[\int_0^1 u(x) dx][\int_0^1 v(x) dx]}$$

I'm wondering if $w$ is continuous around 0, more precisely, if

$$\lim_{||u||_{L_1},|v||_{L_1} \rightarrow 0 } w(u,v)$$

is well defined, where $|| \cdot||_{L_1}= \int_0^1 \cdot dx$. Also, does it matter if I pose it as

$$\lim_{||u||_{L_2},|v||_{L_2} \rightarrow 0 } w(u,v)$$
where $|| \cdot||_{L_2}= (\int_0^1 (\cdot)^2 dx)^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is horribly discontinuous at $0$.  Indeed, notice that for any $\epsilon>0$, $w(\epsilon u,\epsilon v)=w(u,v)$.  So fixing $u$ and $v$ with a given value of $w(u,v)$, then $w$ can also take that value arbitrarily close to $0$ by letting $\epsilon\to 0$.  Since $w$ can take multiple different values, it does not have a well-defined limit at $0$.